# source vs export vs export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, cmake

When compiling applications from source code using `make` or `cmake` the instructions usually say,

`source <some path> <parameter>`

`export <some text>`

Also, a lot of time  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` comes up, being used with `export`.

Whats the difference of `source` and `export` ? Why we need them ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474650/unix-what-is-the-difference-between-source-and-export

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shell commands `source` and `export` are really different things. In short:

**`source`**

When you call a shell script the normal way (say with `./myscript.sh` or `sh myscript.sh`), it will be executed in its own process context (a new process environment), so all variables set in the script will not be available in the calling shell. When executing a script using the `source` command, it will be executed within the context of the calling script. This way you are able to set environment variables by calling `source myscript`.

**`export`**

Environment variables are usually only valid in the (local) context of the current process. So, if you execute something (script or program) which requests a new process environment, the local environment will not be seen within the new process. To pass environment values to a child process, you have to 'export' them by preceeding the assignment with `export`, e.g. `export VAR=value`.

**`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`**

The special environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` defines the path where loadable libraries are searched for (similar to the `PATH`variable, which defines where to look for executables). By default libraries are searched in `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and the like. Libraries installed in non-standard directories (e.g. `/opt/program/lib`) can only be loaded when these paths are additionally defined by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/program/lib` in this example. You need export here, as this must be known to the new process environment your program is running in.

---

**Persistence**

The process environment exists as long as the process is running; this also holds true for the environment variables (when not unset explicitly). If the process is killed (e.g. by closing the terminal window), usually all subprocesses will be killed as well and the environment(s) are deleted. More precisely, this depends on how the child process reacts on `SIGHUP`. If it does not, it will be running further as child of the user process (e.g. `/sbin/upstart --user`) or the init process (PID=1).

One way to have subprocesses overcome the killing of the parent process is to release them from the parent process by using `nohup` command (see `man nohup`), which will not pass `SIGHUP` to the child, and releasing the process to the background:

`nohup <progname> &`

will detach the process from the parent, assign STDIN to `/dev/null` and STDOUT to `./nohup.out`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could you comment on how persistent these commands are ? (i.e. for how long do they keep the variables in memory).

Comment: Environment variables exist as long as the process context exists they are defined in, or until they are undefined explicitly by calling `unset VAR` or (from programs) calling the system function `unsetenv()`. For more and detailed information, look at `man bash` and `man setenv`

Comment: If a terminal is closed would the exported variables not available. (You can answer my comment in your main answer, so that it is more clear.)